# Segmentation fault when accessing array via fscanf

Tags: arrays, c, while-loop, segmentation-fault, scanf

I'm trying to scan integers from a file, then add them to an array. But every time I run the program I get a segmentation fault. Why is this?

```
int main(void) {
    FILE *file;
    int num_in;
    int numbers[10000];

    file = fopen("/Users/foo/aa/extra/sort/rand10k", "r");

    if (file == NULL) 
    {
        perror("Error opening and reading file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int i = 0;

    while (fscanf(file, "%d", &num_in)) 
    {
        numbers[i] = num_in;
        i++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) 
    {
        printf("%d\n", numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

The file in question has 10,000 integers in random order:

[image]

Comment: What does your debugger tell you?

Comment: Nothing. When I run gcc -g, it doesn't say anything in the terminal. On runtime, it just says seg fault

Comment: Aside: the output loop should be `for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { printf("%d\n", numbers[j]); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition in the while loop is incorrect

```
while (fscanf(file, "%d", &num_in))
```

It is evaluated to true even when EOF occurs.

Instead you need to write

```
while ( i < 10000 && fscanf(file, "%d", &num_in) == 1 )
```

After that you should write for example

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
{
    printf("%d\n", numbers[j]);
}
```

Comment: it still wouldn’t cause a segfault, however. the condition should check whether i<10000 to prevent writing beyond the array

Comment: Excellent, that has fixed it. Thanks! However, I don't understand why? 

I thought fscanf returned a non-zero value as long as it was able to execute error free? And then 0 if it wasn't able to scan anything (i.e, end of file). So why the need to specify `==1`?

Comment: @Psi because the array indexing will overrun.

Comment: @MrChasi If the call of fscanf is successful when exactly one argument of fscanf  gets a value

Comment: @WeatherVane that’s what I said. The condition was edited into the answer after my comment

Comment: @MrChasi `fscanf` returns the *number of items successfully scanned* or `EOF`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Exactly. So if it scans nothing, that means it will return 0, no? So if it's EOF, it should return 0, negating the need to specify ==1?

Comment: As stated in the answer, always check for the exact number of conversions needed.

Comment: @MrChasi EOF is a negative integer constant. It is not equal to 0.

Comment: Read the man page section on return value.  "The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs."

Comment: @stark Ohh I see. I had assumed EOF was 0. I didn't realise it could be -1 (which is non-zero). Makes sense why I was seg faulting; I was simply carrying on and overrunning the array

Comment: @WeatherVane What do you mean by "conversions"

Comment: In your case string to int.

Comment: Please read the man page from start to finish.

Comment: @WeatherVane will do. Last question... How do I get the man page?

Comment: The Microsoft function documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crt-alphabetical-function-reference?view=msvc-170) if you care to bookmark it.

Comment: "So if it's EOF, it should return 0," As mentioned earlier, it returns `EOF`, not `0`.

Comment: For most C functions you can just use any search engine and search for `man <function>`. Or you can use the C standard directly instead. There are draft versions available for free.